# Using Styles in Windows Presentation Foundation

Tags: wpf, styles

Imagine I have a data bound ListView and in the `<ControlTemplate.Triggers>`

I have the following

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Status}" Value="Completed">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource CompletedBackground}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
</DataTrigger>
```

I want that to be bound to a Style i have in my Grid.Resources which looks like the following:

```
<Style x:Key="CompletedBackground" TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter>
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFBCFAA6" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFA3E88B" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

However, as you might imagine this doesn't work, suprise suprise, you can't bind "Setter" to "Background", so my question is, how do I actually solve the problem?

I've looked through the following a lot of times, cant find any information [here](http://www.microsoft.com/belux/msdn/nl/community/columns/gillcleeren/wpf_stylesandtriggers.mspx).

Comment: Did you try using a DynamicResource instead of a StaticResource ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do is fundamentally flawed. For starters, your style's setter doesn't specify a target property. Presumably, the target property should be `Background`:

```
<Style x:Key="CompletedBackground" TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFBCFAA6" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFA3E88B" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Secondly, you're then trying to assign a `Style` instance to the `Background` property, which is of type `Brush`, not `Style`.

Depending on exactly what you're trying to achieve, you should be able to just change the `Style` to a `Brush` resource:

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="CompletedBackground" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FFBCFAA6" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFA3E88B" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

Then use it from your trigger in the same fashion you already are.

Comment: Fast answer Kent :). I can't do it faster than you :)). Also I think Filip is referencing style, which is defined inside control template's logical tree. Probably worth mention to define it inside <ControlTemplate.Resources>..</ControlTemplate.Resources>. Not in the grid. Cheers.

Comment: I want it to be globally accessable by all my ListViews, so not only in that controltemplate.

Thanks