# WPF: How to customize SelectionBoxItem in ComboBox

Tags: wpf, templates, combobox, customization

I want to display a custom template/item as selected item in ComboBox (this item does not actually exist in the list of items and is updated differently). This does not even needs to be an item, just providing a custom view would work.

How can I do this while staying within current ComboBox theme (so no ControlTemplate replacement possible)? As far as I see, all of SelectionBox* properties are not editable and internally ComboBox uses unnamed ContentPresenter.

Comment: This is lickly to confuse your users, people expect a combro box to behave as a combro box.

Comment: Well it is a ComboBox with CheckBoxes which might be uncommon, but I would not say this is too confusing (or Evil). Using an additional popup window feels like an overkill, and this element is just not important enough to be a full-size CheckBox list.

Comment: Obviously I can not show a selected item because I do not have a single selected item.

Comment: Check this :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466592/displaying-the-selected-item-differently-in-combobox

Comment: Looks great (DataTrigger/{x:Null}), I will check this later today.

Comment: This is the solution, thanks. Unfortunately I can not approve two answers and Ray Burns provided more detailed (and more specific) solution, so I'll approve his and upvote yours.

Comment: Meh... only 3 reps from being able to retag questions :D

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
<Window.Resources>

  <DataTemplate x:Key="NormalItemTemplate" ...>
    ...
  </DataTemplate>

  <DataTemplate x:Key="SelectionBoxTemplate" ...>
    ...
  </DataTemplate>

  <DataTemplate x:Key="CombinedTemplate">
    <ContentPresenter x:Name="Presenter"
       Content="{Binding}"
       ContentTemplate="{StaticResource NormalItemTemplate}" />
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger
        Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,ComboBoxItem,1}}"
        Value="{x:Null}">
        <Setter TargetName="Presenter" Property="ContentTemplate"
                Value="{StaticResource SelectionBoxTemplate}" />
      </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
  </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>

...

<ComboBox
  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CombinedTemplate}"
  ItemsSource="..."
  ... />
```

The reason this works is that `CombinedTemplate` normally just uses NormalItemTemplate to present its data, but if there is no `ComboBoxItem` ancestor it assumes it is in the selection box so it uses SelectionBoxTemplate.

Note that the three `DataTemplates` could be included in any level of `ResourceDictionary` (not just at the `Window` level) or even directly within the `ComboBox`, depending on your preference.

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely try this one.

Comment: However, this generates a binding exception: `Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem', AncestorLevel='1''`. I think setting `ItemTemplateSelector` is a better approach. Here is an example: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0467c9ca-efb2-4506-96e7-08ce3356860a/combobox-one-template-for-selected-item-one-for-the-dropdown-list?forum=wpf

Comment: This worked for me with a few changes.  I needed to change "Template="{StaticResource NormalItemTemplate}"" to "ContentTemplate="{StaticResource NormalItemTemplate}""  I also had to change Property="Template" to Property="ContentTemplate"

Comment: please update your answer (following the Matt Becker's comment above). I've just upvoted this answer because I've found it helpful mainly by the idea of adding some datatrigger checking if there is any parent ComboBoxItem to switch between normal template and selectionbox template. `Template` is a property supported only for ***Control***, `ContentPresenter` is not a control and it of course does not have such property.

Answer (score 1):

Alexey Mitev's comment on Ray Burns' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2277488/3549027) inspired me to write the following reasonably short utility class, which I now use in all my WPF projects:

```
public class ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public List<DataTemplate> SelectedItemTemplates { get; } = new List<DataTemplate>();
    public List<DataTemplate> DropDownItemTemplates { get; } = new List<DataTemplate>();

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        return GetVisualParent<ComboBoxItem>(container) == null
            ? ChooseFrom(SelectedItemTemplates, item)
            : ChooseFrom(DropDownItemTemplates, item);
    }

    private static DataTemplate ChooseFrom(IEnumerable<DataTemplate> templates, object item)
    {
        if (item == null)
            return null;
        var targetType = item.GetType();
        return templates.FirstOrDefault(t => (t.DataType as Type) == targetType);
    }

    private static T GetVisualParent<T>(DependencyObject child) where T : Visual
    {
        while (child != null && !(child is T))
            child = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
        return child as T;
    }
}
```

With that in the toolbox, it's possible to write XAML like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
     <DataTemplate x:Key="SelectedItemTemplateForInt" DataType="{x:Type system:Int32}">
         <!-- ... -->
     </DataTemplate>

     <DataTemplate x:Key="SelectedItemTemplateForDouble" DataType="{x:Type system:Double}">
         <!-- ... -->
     </DataTemplate>

     <DataTemplate x:Key="DropDownItemTemplateForInt" DataType="{x:Type system:Int32}">
         <!-- ... -->
     </DataTemplate>

     <DataTemplate x:Key="DropDownItemTemplateForDouble" DataType="{x:Type system:Double}">
         <!-- ... -->
     </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplateSelector>
        <local:ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector>
            <local:ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector.SelectedItemTemplates>
                <StaticResource ResourceKey="SelectedItemTemplateForInt" />
                <StaticResource ResourceKey="SelectedItemTemplateForDouble" />
            </local:ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector.SelectedItemTemplates>

            <local:ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector.DropDownItemTemplates>
                <StaticResource ResourceKey="DropDownItemTemplateForInt" />
                <StaticResource ResourceKey="DropDownItemTemplateForDouble" />
            </local:ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector.DropDownItemTemplates>
        </local:ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplateSelector>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have this straight, you want a control that has something arbitrary displayed along with a drop-down button that displays a list of items with checkboxes next to them?

I wouldn't even bother trying to restyle a `ComboBox` to achieve this. The problem is that `ComboBox` is more specialized down a different path than what you need. If you look at the [ComboBox ControlTemplate Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094.aspx), you'll see that it simply uses a `Popup` control to display the list of possible values.

You can take pieces of that template as guidance to creating a `UserControl` that is easier to understand and better provides what you want. You'll even be able to add a `SelectedItems` property and such that `ComboBox` doesn't provide.

An example of what I mean by guidance: the `Popup` has an `IsOpen` property. In the control template, it's set to `{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}`, which means that the `ComboBox` class has an `IsDropDownOpen` property that is changed in order to control the expand/collapse of the `Popup`.

Comment: The problem with custom controls are that they are not styled by built-in styles. I have already build a custom control with SelectedItems, but inside it relies on a ComboBox since I want default styles to work with it without repeating them.

Answer (score -1):

You need to look into [Triggers](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/GuidedTourWPF_4.aspx) and [Styles](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/GuidedTourWPF_5.aspx). You might also want to look into some of my older questions here on StackOverflow that helped me conquer these problems:

- [Displaying Content only when ListViewItem is Selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708428/displaying-content-only-when-listviewitem-is-selected)
- [Using Styles in Windows Presentation Foundation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486500/using-styles-in-windows-presentation-foundation)

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that was kind of too abstract as compared to other answers. I have a general idea of how triggers work, it was the {x:Null} solution I couldn't invent.