# In wpf how can i associate a window with the popup of a combobox

Tags: wpf-controls

I want to create a WPF combobox which should have 2 listboxes alongwith ok and cancel buttons in its Part_Popup.  How to go about it? Simply put showin a dialogbox on dropdown event with all other functionality intact.
I tried to implement a custom combobox using FrameworkElementFactory but the result is too bad: 1) Its very difficult to select the inner listview items and 2) the whole dialogbox(panel) remains selected as if its an item of combobox(which sure it is but i dont want that)..

Answer (score 0):

Look at this answer:

[WPF Combobox: Different template in textbox and drop-downlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671986/wpf-combobox-different-template-in-textbox-and-drop-downlist)

The ComboBox.ItemTemplate section contains the closed version of the ComboBox.

The StackPanel section adds two labels (title and branch name) to the popup. Instead of labels you can add your buttons.