# wpf combobox with custom itemtemplate text

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, combobox, itemtemplate

I have `ComboBox` with custom `ItemTemplate`.

```
<ComboBox Height="20" Width="200" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedDesign}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Designs}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False">

    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type formdesign:FormDesignContainer}">
            <Rectangle Width="200" Height="100">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Path=ImageThumb}" Stretch="Uniform" />
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

</ComboBox>
```

This works well. However WPF tries to draw rectangle as Combobox Text. How can I set "text" for this template. By "text" I mean string or control which represent selected item and write into combobox when item is selected

In other words I'd like to do this:

[image]

But now I got this

[image]

Comment: Can you please post the code of the type of the items you put into the ComboBox? I think I don't fully understand the problem yet.

Comment: My object derived from Canvas

Comment: So the `Designs`-property is of some kind of  `IEnumerable<Canvas>`? Where does the text you want to display come from?

Comment: Name property. As I know Canvas also have Name

Comment: I want to display rectangles in drop-down list, and as text I'd like to show Name property

Comment: @Spontifixus look at update

Comment: Now your question is clear. I don't have time for an elaborate answer at the moment, but you will need to create a control template for the entire `ComboBox` showing the string "Design" when it is focused. Keep in mind that this is not a default behavior of a windows combo box - and thus not what a user might expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Try setting SelectionBoxItemTemplate with a TextBlock.</strike>
Appears that SelectionBoxItemTemplate is read-only. So another approach is to override ItemContainerStyle.Template. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3672098/1077059)

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214696/wpf-how-to-customize-selectionboxitem-in-combobox/2277488#2277488) solution by *Ray Burns* a good approach. You can define two `DataTemplate` one for Items in the drop down list and the other for the selected item which should be shown in the `Combobox`. The using a trigger and checking the visual tree it decide which one to use.

```
<Window.Resources>    
  <DataTemplate x:Key="NormalItemTemplate" ...>
    ...
  </DataTemplate>

  <DataTemplate x:Key="SelectionBoxTemplate" ...>
    ...
  </DataTemplate>

  <DataTemplate x:Key="CombinedTemplate">
    <ContentPresenter x:Name="Presenter"
       Content="{Binding}"
       ContentTemplate="{StaticResource NormalItemTemplate}" />
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger
        Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,ComboBoxItem,1}}"
        Value="{x:Null}">
        <Setter TargetName="Presenter" Property="ContentTemplate"
                Value="{StaticResource SelectionBoxTemplate}" />
      </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
  </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>

...

<ComboBox
  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CombinedTemplate}"
  ItemsSource="..."/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add Textblock to the datatemplate and bind it 
or add Contentpersenter on the rectangle
Edit:
it seems like i didn't got what you were tring to accomplish ,