# WPF Calendar as ComboBoxItem

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, calendar

I have a `ComboBox` where the `ComboBoxItem` has a `Grid` with a `Calendar` inside.

The problem is that by clicking next to month label the drop down gets closed and the ComboBox changes as shown in the figure.

[image: Starting condition] [image: Problem]

This happens only by clicking there. All the other behaviours are right.

I don't know which event creates this problem..any help is really appreciate!

This is the `ComboBox` xaml definition:

```
 <ComboBox Height="46" Width="180" Text="{mhira3D:TranslateMarkup Value1 = filteringComboBox}" Margin="0,0,8,0" IsEditable="False" Tag="../Assets/Icons/filter.svg"
                          IsReadOnly="True" Style="{DynamicResource OneItemOnlyComboBox}"
                          IsDropDownOpen="{Binding FilterConcluded}">
     <ComboBox.IsEnabled>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BooleanAndConverter}">
                <Binding Path="ChartViewModel.NotDbErrorOccured" />
                <Binding Path="ChartViewModel.AtLeastOneRoiSelected" />
            </MultiBinding>
     </ComboBox.IsEnabled>
     <ComboBoxItem Style="{DynamicResource ComboBoxItemNoMouseOver}">
           <Grid Width="490">
                 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
                 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <...Definition of the buttons...>
            <Viewbox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4">
                     <Calendar Name="CalendarFilter" SelectionMode="SingleRange"
                               IsTodayHighlighted="True" 
                               BorderBrush="{DynamicResource StandardBorderColor}"                                          SelectedDatesChanged="Calendar_OnSelectedDatesChanged">
                               <Calendar.BlackoutDates>
                                        <CalendarDateRange Start="{x:Static local:OverallChartWindow.Tomorrow}"
                                                           End="{x:Static sys:DateTime.MaxValue}" />
                                </Calendar.BlackoutDates>
                            </Calendar>
                        </Viewbox>
                     </Grid>
                 </ComboBoxItem>
              </ComboBox>
```

And this is the `ComboBoxItem` style:

```
 <Style x:Key="ComboBoxItemNoMouseOver" TargetType="ComboBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBoxItem}}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                <Border>
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Rectangle Fill="{DynamicResource StandardBackgroundColor}" 
                                   IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="fillColor" Fill="{DynamicResource DisabledGray}"
                                   IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                   Opacity="0" Stroke="{DynamicResource StandardBorderColor}"
                                   StrokeThickness="2" />
                        <ContentControl x:Name="contentControl"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                        Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" IsHitTestVisible="False">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" />
                        </ContentControl>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: When playing around with comboboxes in a grid, there's two templates you usually need to set. One is ItemTemplate and the other is CellEditTemplate. It looks like you don't have a CellEditTemplate defined.

Comment: I can't understand, I'm sorry..the grid is in the ComboBoxItem. Where should I define CellEditTemplate?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671986/wpf-combobox-different-template-in-textbox-and-drop-downlist

Comment: So you'll want to define ItemTemplate and ItemContainerStyle